# Debug typescript files with chrome

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, typescript

I'm looking for option to allow debug `*.ts` files while developing application using nodeJS.

Right now, grunt compiling `*.ts` files to `.tmp/scripts`. In my `index.html` file all `*.js` files are referenced.

Is there a possibility to debug my application using `*.ts` files while developing application with node.js?

I'm using `Yeoman angular-typescript generator`

Answer (score 0):

In order to have possibility to debug ts files (both client side - in chrome, or server side in node.js) you must generate map.js files that will bind your original typescript files with resulting js ones.

More info on js maps here: [js maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)

To enable js maps in grunt specify corresponding flag in gruntfile.js like this:

```
   options: {
                module: 'commonjs',
                target: 'es5',
                sourceMap: true
            }
```

Comment: I have maps generated. My problem is: When I debug using ie. Chrome `*.ts` files are not listed in the chrome debugger

Comment: check that you have source maps enabled in chrome settings: http://dannycroft.co.uk/enabling-source-maps-in-chrome/